# AddFontResourceW after create new Font object

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, pinvoke

i have got some problems with adding custom fonts, after creating a font object.
Here is some demo code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "AddFontResourceW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int AddFontResource([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]

public void Demo()
{
var font = new Font("Roboto", 8); //Create roboto font. Not installed yet, then use Times New Roman. Ok!
var result = AddFontResource(@"C:\Roboto.ttf"); //Install roboto font until system reboots (Sample filename). result == 1. Ok!
var test = SendMessage(0xffff, 0x001D, 0, 0);
font = new Font("Roboto", 8); //Font should be roboto, but still Times New Roman. 
}
```

Then following demo works:

```
public void Demo()
{
var result = AddFontResource(@"C:\Roboto.ttf"); //Install roboto font until system reboots (Sample filename). result == 1. Ok!
var test = SendMessage(0xffff, 0x001D, 0, 0);
var font = new Font("Roboto", 8); //Font is roboto. OK!
}
```

Could somebody tell me why AddFontResourceW only works, if no font object was created earlier? Or how can i get the first example to run properly?

Comment: perhaps caching in gdi+?

Comment: Why you do not use [PrivateFontCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-private-font-collection) class instead?

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps. I don't know.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: I tested it. But with PrivateFontCollection you can't use the familyName string in the constructor. Only an item from FontCollection.Families array works to create the font object.